Extract type from branded type
How can I extract the type of a branded type in TypeScript?
It works on non literal brands:
type Branded = string & {
  brand: string;
};

type Extract_I<T> = T extends infer V & { brand: string } ? V : never;

type Result_I = Extract_I<Branded>; // => string

But not for literal brands:
type LiteralBranded = string & {
  brand: 'brand';
};

type Result_II = Extract_I<LiteralBranded>; // =>  string & { brand: "brand" }

How can I make this work?
This is something else I've tried:
type Extract_II<T> = T extends { brand: string } ? T & { brand: never } : never; // does not work.


You need to infer the brand's type first:
Playground
type Extract_I<T> = T extends { brand: infer X } ? T extends infer V & { brand: X } ? V : never : never;


WOW! Thanks alot! I really thought it wasn't possible..
